# Non-destructive flattening of animated models?

Tags: modeling, animation

In the game Super Smash Bros. Melee, there is a stage called Flat Zone, which flattens every playable character along the z-axis, as if they are within the screen of the Game & Watch handheld. All of the characters still use their regular 3D models and their respective animations that were animated in a 3D space, but the stage permanently flattens all of it, making them appear paper-thin when you rotate the camera. The character Mr. Game & Watch, who also uses a normal 3D model, is permanently flattened in a similar manner, regardless of the stage he's on.

Here are examples taken from Super Smash Bros. Ultimate:

### Normal 3D View

[image: 3D Front]
[image: 3D Side]

### "2D" View

[image: 2D Front]
[image: 2D Side]

Is there a way to achieve such an effect in Blender in a non-destructive manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flatten a geometry on an arbitrary axis like this : create a new object, delete all geometry (in edit mode), and create a geometry nodes modifier like this :

[image: Geometry nodes for flattening]

This joins all the objects contained in your character, regardless of their own transformations, and flattens them on the X axis.

Setting the multiplying factor to 0 would have mesh elements overlap and cause [z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting), so I advise setting it to a very low value instead (as pictured). This will also ensure the depth order is respected, so your character should more or less look like the original (when viewed from the side, at least).

[image: Flattened animated character 01]
[image: Flattened animated character 02]
[image: Flattened animated character 03]

Comment: I don't know if I did something wrong, but it doesn't quite work yet. It flattens the model alright, but the animation doesn't get translated into the flat plane properly. If part of the model is rotated for example, the previously flat model now deforms into the axis it's not supposed to be deformed into.

Comment: Modifiers work in object space, so any object-level rotation will change the "flattening plane". In order to solve this, I would have to know more about your particular use case.

Comment: I'll try to upload a GIF of an example when I have time and I'm at my PC, but the low upload size limit here is giving me trouble.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, I've finally added some example GIFs. I hope this gets my point across better than my words could.

Comment: What doesn't work with the method I suggested ? does your character use an armature ?

Comment: Yes, I used an armature. I don't "have" a character at the moment to easily test these things, I just used the default monkey model, slapped a simple rig on it, made a simple animation, and checked how your solution would look like on that animation. As I mentioned, the model doesn't stay flat, part of it sticks out from the third axis when it shouldn't.

Comment: Yes, this is going to happen unless you scale down to 0. Try it, but it may mess up the depth sorting on your geometry.

I think developers of the game may have a different way of going about it. They probably swap the model for a flat card that's textured with renders of the actual 3D model. It works because it's a game, and there's only a finite amount of animations the character can have. I guess now it depends on what you want to do with this technique. A short film ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... what should I scale down to 0 exactly? Did you get this to work with an animation? If so, can you post a GIF of it? I'm curious to see how it looks like in motion on your side. As for why I asked my original question, I don't really have any plans for this, I just wanted to experiment with the look, that's all.

Comment: The vector math node that does the flattening, see my capture.

Comment: Added information in the original answer

Comment: It seems to me problem is related to the order of operations. You want all the armatures and stuff to be evaluated BEFORE your flatten and rotate the object. And this answer seems to do just that. It could use a Collection Info instead of multiple Object Infos for convenience, but the key information is to not use e.g. an armature on the geonodes object - the geonodes object should be the last element of evaluation, except for rotations and other stuff that already treats the object as a plane.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I didn't see the notification. You were right, I had the modifiers in the wrong order... such a stupid mistake, I apologize. Thank you for your help!